# if i enter today's date its shows me day before date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, datepicker

i enterd todays date but in my tasks its shows day before date for example if i entered 1/7/2020 in my task it show 30/6/2020  i tried by removing time but still 00:00 shows up i am not getting why its shows previous date

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import database from '../firebase/firebase';
import '../App.css';

const AddTasks = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const newLocal = null;
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(newLocal);
    const [task, setTask] = useState('');
    const date = new Date()
    const userId = useSelector(state => state.auth.uid);


    const addTask = () => {
        console.log(userId);
        console.log('addedAt');
        const payload = { id: uuid(), text: task, completed: false, addedAt: JSON.stringify(selectedDate)}
        const dbtasksWrapper = database.ref().child(userId).child('tasks');
        return dbtasksWrapper.child(payload.id).update(payload).then(() => {
            setTask('');
            setSelectedDate(null);
            dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASKS", payload })
        })
     }

return (
    <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault(e.target.value);
        addTask();
    } }>
        <input className="input-group-prepend" value={task} placeholder="Enter your Task" onChange={e => setTask(e.target.value)} />
```

> i have remove time but still getting 00:00 im my tasks list

```
<DatePicker className="input-group-prepend" 
            placeholderText="Enter task date " 
            selected={selectedDate} onChange={(date) => setSelectedDate(date)} 
            
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy " 
        minDate={date} />
        <br />
        <input className="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>
);
};
export default AddTasks;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing? You can't pick a date prior to today's date? You're seeing a 00:00 at the end of your date?

Comment: yes because of that it shows me perivious date

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're problem is that you're setting the `minDate` prop on the `Datepicker` to today (I.e. `new Date()`). To fix this, all you need to do is remove the prop like so:

```js
return (
  <form
    onSubmit={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault(e.target.value);
      addTask();
    }}
  >
    <input
      className="input-group-prepend"
      value={task}
      placeholder="Enter your Task"
      onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)}
    />
    <DatePicker
      // No `minDate` prop here anymore!
      className="input-group-prepend"
      placeholderText="Enter task date"
      selected={selectedDate}
      onChange={(date) => setSelectedDate(date)}
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
    />
    <br />
    <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
);
```

Or, here's a link to a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dawn-ctttl?file=/src/AddTasks.js).

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am sorry its not working i will try to add local time mybe this will help i will try that and update thanx for your efforts really appreciate it

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like we're still not on the same page. Can give an example of the date that's being given and the date that you want?

Comment: sur   "2020-07-01T20:00:00.000Z" its giving me date like this i have entered 2020-07-02 time 11:30 Am  i want it to show me date like this